# How do I make an array of arrays out of a CSV?

Tags: ruby

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Jenny, jenny@example.com ,
Ricky, ricky@example.com ,
Josefina josefina@example.com ,
```

I'm trying to get this output:

```
users_array = [
['Jenny', 'jenny@example.com'], ['Ricky', 'ricky@example.com'], ['Josefina', 'josefina@example.com']
]
```

I've tried this:

```
users_array = Array.new

file = File.new('csv_file.csv', 'r') 
file.each_line("\n") do |row| 
    puts row + "\n" 
    columns = row.split(",") 
    users_array.push columns 
    puts users_array
end
```

Unfortunately, in Terminal, this returns:

```
Jenny
jenny@example.com
Ricky
ricky@example.com
Josefina
josefina@example.com
```

Which I don't think will work for this:

```
users_array.each_with_index do |user|
    add_page.form_with(:id => 'new_user') do |f|
      f.field_with(:id => "user_email").value = user[0]
      f.field_with(:id => "user_name").value = user[1]
    end.click_button
end
```

What do I need to change? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your CSV file actually has a comma between the name and email address on the third line:

```
require 'csv'

users_array = []
CSV.foreach('csv_file.csv') do |row|
  users_array.push row.delete_if(&:nil?).map(&:strip)
end

users_array
# => [["Jenny", "jenny@example.com"],
#     ["Ricky", "ricky@example.com"],
#     ["Josefina", "josefina@example.com"]]
```

There may be a simpler way, but what I'm doing there is discarding the `nil` field created by the trailing comma and `strip`ping the spaces around the email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's standard library has a [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class with a similar api to `File` but contains a number of useful methods for working with tabular data. To get the output you want, all you need to do is this:

```
require 'csv'
users_array = CSV.read('csv_file.csv')
```

PS - I think you are getting the output you expected with your file parsing as well, but maybe you're thrown off by how it is printing to the terminal. `puts` behaves differently with arrays, printing each member object on a new line instead of as a single array. If you want to view it as an array, use `puts my_array.inspect`.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails on two counts: 1) there's a trailing `nil` at the end of each Array, and 2) there are spaces around the email addresses.

Comment: I love this .inspect tip. Thanks.